# How to make insert data with checker when value exist the insert function not triggered

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to make an insert function with php mysqli. 
But before I do the insert function I need to check the value in the table does not exist. My value is an array. I am really don't know how to do it.

The checker will be checking
`'".$item['no_pol']."'`,`'".$item['date']."'`,`'".$item['time']."'` when that Value exist the insert function will not run.

This is the code I just made. I would appreciated when help me with an example.

```html
<?php
include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");
if(isset($_POST['table-bordered'])){
 $array=json_decode($_POST['table-bordered'],true);
 foreach($array as $item) {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO wjm (sloc,kode,nama,no_pol,id,date,netto,uses,unit,payroll,time) VALUES ('".$item['sloc']."', '".$item['kode']."', '".$item['nama']."', '".$item['no_pol']."', '".$item['id']."', '".$item['date']."', '".$item['netto']."', '".$item['Unit']."', '".$item['uses']."', '".$item['payroll']."', '".$item['time']."')";
  if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
     echo "Records inserted successfully.";
  } else{
     echo "Records inserted failed ";
  } 

     }
}else{
 false;
}

?>
```

Comment: Are these 3 columns the primary key of the table? If so, duplicates will not be allowed by the DB, causing an error when attempting to insert. Otherwise simply do a select or count select for these 3 columns and if any results are returned, do not insert. `select count(*) from wjm where no_pol=<value1> and date=<value2> and time=<value3>`.

Comment: @William_Wilson that's not a primary key,
`<value1>,<value2>,<value3>` ? the syntax for that value just same with my code that contain the data like `'".$item['no_pol']."','".$item['date']."','".$item['time']."'`

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here. Are you unable to make the swap from <value#> for $item array values? E.g.: `'select count(*) from wjm where no_pol='.$item['no_po;'].' and date='.$item['date'].' and time='.$item['time']'`. Note this style of appending without sanitizing the values is not good design, unless these values are generated and guaranteed trustworthy.

Comment: @William_Wilson not like that..
from my code the data has been converted into `$array as $item` right.
nah from your code that you said to me i want to know what is the syntax for `<value1>` that you made. is it contain of my `$item` or use your syntax

Answer (score 0):

Just run a query and use row count to determine if it exists:
choose a select column that's unique per column, like for example a list of employee ID numbers, do id=231231.

If nothing is unique, then you could try a WHERE with multiple key conditions but that's not advised.

```
foreach($array as $item){

 $sql = "SELECT no_pol, date, time from wjm WHERE no_pol = ? AND date = ? AND time = ?";   
// some unique combination

  if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$item['no_pol'],$item['date'],$item['time']);
    $stmt->execute()
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
  }

if($rows == 0){
  //do your insert
}else{
  //don't insert and say record exists
}
}
```

Comment: You should format the query to represent the 3 columns requested and if you're going to return data instead of a count, the query should be limited. Since this isn't the primary key and you are storing the results a lot of wasted time could be spent collecting the non-indexed columns and transferring data that will not be used.

Comment: I didn't intend to give him the answer, I intended to give him a format that he could build off and use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the SELECT query which return the count of records so,if record is not present in database table means SELECT query returns 0 that means COUNT will be 0 and when **COUNT == 0** at that time you have to execute your INSERT query just as follow:

```
    <?php
        include("../../Connections/koneksi.php");
        if(isset($_POST['table-bordered'])){
            $array=json_decode($_POST['table-bordered'],true);
            foreach($array as $item) {
                $sql_query = "Select count('*') from wjm where no_pol = '".$item['no_pol']."' AND date = '".$item['date']."' AND time = '".$item['time']."'";
                if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_query)){
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    /** Check the count of returned records **/
                    if($count == 0){
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO wjm (sloc,kode,nama,no_pol,id,date,netto,uses,unit,payroll,time) VALUES ('".$item['sloc']."', '".$item['kode']."', '".$item['nama']."', '".$item['no_pol']."', '".$item['id']."', '".$item['date']."', '".$item['netto']."', '".$item['Unit']."', '".$item['uses']."', '".$item['payroll']."', '".$item['time']."')";
                        if(mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
                            echo "Records inserted successfully.";
                        } else{
                            echo "Records inserted failed ";
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            false;
        }
    ?>
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: and i try to find the eror but nothing display